# How to get only value of a column in Php without column name

Tags: php, sql

I have a table like

[image]

I want to write a query in php so that I just get the value of companycolumn and not the column name along.

I have written the following code :

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","nets") or die("Couldn't connect to database");
 $query4 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT company from new_table where Name='Abc';") 
while($row123 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4)){
  foreach($row123 as $key => $value){
    echo $value;
    echo $row123[$key];
  }
}
```

The echo gives me the column name and not the value of the column. How to print only the column value in Php.

```
Output :
company

Required output:
lenovo
```

Comment: please also update your query result means these echo result and what you want actually in that

Comment: why are you having nested loops?

Comment: I think the output is in an array so will traverse through the array to get the value and not the column name.

Comment: What happens if you `echo $row123['country'];`?

Comment: Returns the column name "country"

Comment: and then what if you try `$row123['Country'];`? Same thing?

Comment: error when casing issue else the column name and not the value

Comment: Can you dump the `$row123` var at first line in `while` loop?: `while($row123 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4)){ var_dump($row123);`. This will show you the value of the entire `$row123` construct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139116/discussion-between-learner-and-joshweir).

Comment: this screenshot has no country

Comment: there was a tiny syntax error in the posters original code, the issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat associated to this question. The SQL was actually part of a larger block of PHP code which was dynamically generating SQL that looked like this:

```
$query = "select '$varname' from thetable";
```

This resulted in selecting the column name as a string rather than a column. For example, if `$varname = "country";` the output was `country`. Using the backquotes fixed it:

```
$query = "select `$varname` from thetable"
```

This ensured that the SQL column was selected.

Answer (score 0):

No need for nested loops. The inner `foreach` you are trying to traverse a single row not an array.
Try

```
while($row123 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4)){
 echo $row123['country'];
}
```

Comment: still prints "country"

Comment: @Learner what if you replace the echo in the code above with `printf ("%s\n", $row123["Country"]);` ?

Comment: Same result. No changes.

Comment: can you post the result of `var_dump($row123);` in your question?

Comment: array(1) { ["Country"]=> string(7) "Country" }  This is the output.

Comment: that means you have stored value country in your country column please check your table data